# Make vim switch to other window after opening a diff

Tags: autocmd, vimdiff

99% of the time when I am opening a diff (using the `:diffsplit` command), it's because I want to reference some code, but still edit the file I started in. However, whenever you open a diff with diffsplit, the new file gets focus. I'd like to make vim automatically switch back (Or not switch in the first place if that's an option). I didn't see anything about it in `diffopt` so I tried an autocmd to accomplish this but to no avail:

```
autocmd FilterWritePost * if(&diff) | wincmd w
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to use `wincmd p` to go to the previous window.

Comment: No dice. It still has no effect.

Comment: how do you "open a diff"?

Comment: Using the `:diffsplit` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Diffsplit diffsplit <args> | wincmd p
```

This create a `Diffsplit` command (note the capitalized `D`) which takes one argument and accept file names as completion.

The command will create the diffsplit with the argument provided and use the command `windcm p` to go back to the initial file.

See [`:h user-commands`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#user-commands) and [`:h wincmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#wincmd).

Comment: This is a good workaround, but I'd like to see if anyone can come up with an "official" solution.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by an "official" solution?

Comment: Sorry, what I should have said was, "able to use the vim command `:diffsplit`." So not using an alias command. But it looks like this isn't possible. So I'll probably wait a few more days then give it to you if nothing else shows up. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Tumbler41 Oh ok I get it now. Well maybe someone will come up with a clever solution which will not require a custom command but I'm really not sure that is possible :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find the source code defining the `diffsplit` command: [vim/vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/7c0a2f367f2507669560b1a66423155c70d2e75b/src/diff.c#L1069-L1106), let see what it does:

1. It set some reference to the old window, as we will create a new one.
2. It disable the tab opening
3. Split the window (create a new window, that where the `old_curwin` is useful)
4. Edit the desired file
5. Check that we are on a new window
6. Set the diffs options for the current window
7. Check the old window is still a valid window
8. Set the diffs options for the old window
9. Check the old buffer reference is still valid
10. Change the **line number** to match the one of the old window.

As you can see, there is nothing in this function that change the cursor from the new window to the original one. I think the official* answer is that "it's by design that you stay on the new window".

Now, you can, as other answer suggested, use an autocommand to add the `switch to original` step, I think it's the best you can do.

* From what I understand, I wont talk for the official Vim maintainers.

---

Why your autocomand does not work:

When you do

```
autocmd FilterWritePost * ...
```

And it is called from the `diffsplit` command, both files will trigger this event (and both files will have the `&diff` variable set), you can check that with the following autocommand:

```
:autocmd FilterWritePre * if &diff | echomsg expand('%')
```

I think your best solution is still to use a custom command.

---

I have tried to work with the following autocommand events: `BufEnter`, `BufWinEnter`, `OptionSet`, `WinEnter`.

But none of them gave results, because it gets triggered two times, or because it gets triggered before the buffer has the `diff` option set.

Once more, I think your best solution is to use a custom command.

Comment: An autocmd would be great. If you look at the question you'll see that I tried to create one,  but couldn't get it to work. Could you give an example of an autocmd that would do this?

Comment: Updated, I don't think an autocommand is suited for this :/